# Format java string to look a specific way

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am new to Java and I have 4 int stacks that I need to print out in a specific way. The IDE I am using is BlueJ.

I want to print the arrays to look like the following

```
 |110|   |231|   |333|   |444|
 |111|   |232|   |334|   |447|
 |112|   |233|   |335|   |448|
 |113|   |234|   |336|   |449|
 |114|   |235|   |337|   |450|
 |115|   |236|   |338|   |451|
```

I am trying to this with `System.out.println("|"+stack1.pop()+"|")` but it creates a problem because I am not sure how to go back from the bottom, back to the top. Ex. 115 --> back up to 231. Each column represents a stack.

Thank you!

Comment: Why the Android tag? This seems to be purely Java, especially since you're using BlueJ and `println()`

Comment: @A--C I will eventually be moving to Android so my mistake for including it in there. I really do not think it was worth a down vote

Comment: I *didn't* downvote you (since it's a small mistake), but I *did* remove the tag.

Comment: @A--C My apologies... happend at the same time

Comment: The order of the elements is not clear in your question. For example consider the first column/stack a `pop()` operation will print `115` or `110`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.format()` better than concatenating a bunch of strings

```
System.out.println(String.format("|%s|\t|%s|\t|%s|\t|%s|",
                            stack1.pop(),stack2.pop(),stack3.pop(),stack4.pop()));
```

If you want to print the `Stack` elements in the opposite order, just `reverse` the stack first

Comment: You can also pad each string with a specified number of spaces (rather than using the tab symbol).

Comment: @itech why to worry about that string concatenations as during compilation those `+` will merely be replace by StringBuilder`s append() and thats pretty fast

Comment: It depend on the compiler implementation and it is not necessary to be done in the most efficient way. Additionally, using `String.format` is more readable and give you more control in formatting the output

Comment: You're both right: this way is better **AND** the compiler would probably do it anyways...

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to do that in console:
as an alternative you can print values from each stack and then moving down like:

```
System.out.println("|"+stack1.pop()+"|\t|"+stack2.pop()+"|\t|"+stack3.pop()+"|\t|"+stack4.pop()+"|" );
```

**Edit**
as commented - you can use [String.format(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) , check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for formatting options available

Comment: @jahroy I dont think we will still be able to move back to the first line - even if we use `String.fortmat` , if I am wrong plz feel free to put an example

Comment: Sorry... I re-read the question after making that comment and deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
    ArrayList<Stack<Integer>> arrays=new ArrayList<Stack<Integer>>();
    arrays.add(stack1);
    arrays.add(stack2);
    arrays.add(stack3);
    arrays.add(stack4);

//Put some code here to  Determine the stack size, if all are unequal in size   
    int size=stack1.size(); 


    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        String value="";
        String temp="";
```

//4 = if you know the number of stacks is going to be 4 only

```
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){ 

            //Handle here Empty Stack Exception and print blank
            value="|"+(String)(arrays.get(j)).pop().toString()+"|"+" ";
            temp=temp+value;


        }

        System.out.println(temp);



    }
```